# Elif statement occuring when it shouldn't when finding an item in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here but I want it so if they typed 'bloof' with a spelling error it would say "Item not found" but with the elif statement here even if you type "blood" it still calls that "Item not found"

If you take out the elif statement, typing "blood" calls the item but with the elif statement it always says "Item not found"

```
    shopitemsF = ["Ghostblade: 150 Damage, Cost: 700", "Thunderblade: 120 Damage, Cost: 300",
          "Bloodcursed Sword: 200 Damage, Cost: 950"]

    shopchoice = input("Please choose an item from the shop by typing part of its name: ")
    shopchoice = shopchoice.title()

    for text2 in shopitemsF:
        if shopchoice in text2:
            print(text2)
        elif shopchoice not in text2:
            print("Item not found.")
            shopchoice = input("Please pick another item? ")
```

Comment: You are checking each item in the list . If the first item does not contain blood then the else statement will kick in and ask you for another input. What you want is to check whether a match was found after you check all items in the list.

Comment: Also notice that an elif is not needed. This is just an else.

Comment: Oh that makes sense I didn't think it was doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach, and solution below, which fixes the bug in your approach isn't going to scale.

```
found = False
for text2 in shopitemsF:
    if shopchoice in text2:
        found = True
        break

if not found:
    print("Item not found.")
    shopchoice = input("Please pick another item? ")
else:
    print("Item found")
```

I am saying not scalabe because if you have N items in `shopitemsF` and each item has an average length of `M`, this search is going to be O(NM) - managable for small N and small M but with thousands of records, it's going to be very slow.

Comment: Yep this worked and now I know why thanks to @Thanassis.

Comment: Glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're only checking the first item before entering the if statement.

You should do something like:

```
res = ""
for text2 in shopitemsF:
    if shopchoice in text2:
        res = text2
if res != "":
    print(res)
else:
    print("Item not found.")
    shopchoice = input("Please pick another item? ")
```

Personally, I would write it like this:

```
shopitemsF = ["Ghostblade: 150 Damage, Cost: 700", "Thunderblade: 120 Damage, Cost: 300",
"Bloodcursed Sword: 200 Damage, Cost: 950"]

item_not_found = True
while item_not_found:
    shopchoice = input("Please choose an item from the shop by typing part of its name: ")
    shopchoice = shopchoice.title()
    for text2 in shopitemsF:
        if shopchoice in text2:
            print(text2)
            item_not_found = False
            break
    if item_not_found:
        print("Item not found.")
```

So that it loops everytime an item isn't found and reprompts the user.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean.

Comment: So in your code you enter the for-loop, check if the first item contains `blood`, and then tell the user the item was not found. As opposed to checking ALL items before informing the user.

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking your input with all the available items in the list, just with the first one. You need to loop through all of them in order to be sure that your input is not in any of them. Further, you need to recurse back to your input check if the input is invalid. Something like:

```
# start by initializing the input:
shopchoice = input("Please choose an item from the shop by typing part of its name: ")
while True:  # main decision loop, repeat until we have a valid input
    shopchoice = shopchoice.title()  # capitalize the first letter
    found = None  # holds our found element, if any
    for text2 in shopitemsF:  # loop through all of the elements in the list
        if shopchoice in text2:  # check if the input is in the current element
            found = text2  # it is, store it in found for use bellow
            break  # item found, no need to search further, comment if you want the last item
    if found:  # we've found an element in the previous loop
        print(found)  # print it...
        break  # exit the main decision loop
    else:  # item was not found
        print("Item not found.")  
        shopchoice = input("Please pick another item? ")  # request for another input, repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your for loop, you are looping through the entire list and applying the check on each one. As there are two items in the array and you are only testing for one you are getting both results back each time.
To fix this you simply add a  `break` into your loop. Looking something like this:

```
for text2 in shopitemsF:
    if shopchoice in text2:
        print(text2)
        break
```

And since you do not want "item not found" for every item in the array that doesn't match I would recommend instead creating a variable to store whether the item was found, combined with a while loop to trigger the shop again if the item wasn't found and an entry that ends the loop if the player doesn't want to make a purchase:

```
shopitemsF = ["Ghostblade: 150 Damage, Cost: 700", "Thunderblade: 120 Damage, Cost: 300",
      "Bloodcursed Sword: 200 Damage, Cost: 950"]

shopchoice = input("Please choose an item from the shop by typing part of its name: ")

while True:
    shopchoice = shopchoice.title()

    if shopchoice == "End":
        break

    found = False
    for text2 in shopitemsF:
        if shopchoice in text2:
            found = text2
            break

    if found != False:
        print(found)
        break

    print("Item not found.")
    shopchoice = input("Please pick another item? ")
```